# Integration Testing of BotFramework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have seen some videos and tutorials on integrating testing with super agent or super test. I can't figure out the API to build a test with one of the frameworks. Does anyone know where the API is documented?

If not, had anyone tried this? I tried using fiddler to observe the emulator but was in over my head or was not capturing what I needed.

The only testing I have seen us the basic asset libs in the BotBuilder GutHub repos.

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Connector API is documented here: http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi/

The Messages operations will probably be most interesting for you. http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/restapi/#!/Messages/Messages_SendMessage